# C++ how to use std::find properly

Tags: c++, arrays, int, find, qt-creator

I got a question about one article in www.cplusplus.com and exactly about [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) which is function from the Algorithm library. Here is my code.

Code in randnum.cpp:

```
#include "randnum.h"

void randNum (char timeATM)
{
    int *p, newRandNum;

    srand (timeATM);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        newRandNum = rand() % 10;
        p = std::find(randNums, randNums + 4, newRandNum);
        if (p != randNums + 4)
        {
            std::cout << "!found! at " << i + 1 << "| num " << *p << std::endl;
            i = i - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            randNums[i] = Nums[newRandNum];
            std::cout << "all ok; at " << i + 1 << "| num " << randNums[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Code in randnum.h:

```
#ifndef RANDNUM_H
#define RANDNUM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int Nums [10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int randNums [4];

#endif // RANDNUM_H
```

So the question is what the second argument `randNums + 4` in the function `std::find(randNums, randNums + 4, newRandNum);` does?

Also the idea of this piece of code is to generate one number from 0 to 9 and make sure there aren't any doubled numbers, for example the number three isn't used 2 times. But i saw that when the first generated number of the array (randNums[0]) is zero, the program decides that there is already a zero in the string so it skips it and generates another number. Can you explain me why does this happen and how to fix it?

www.cplusplus.com was supposed to be link, but i am limited only to two links.. so.. sorry. And sorry for any mistakes within the code and the question.

Comment: We have some issues with reading links.

Comment: In addition to cplusplus.com, your C++ book will also have a description of `std::find`. If you are unable to understand that explanation at all, what makes you think that any explanation you get here will be more understandable to you? If there's something specific about the description of `std::find`, and its parameter, then you need to explain exactly what you are unclear about.

Comment: @NeilButterworth at least the links are working properly so just answer the question if you have any ideas or don't show us how smart you can be in the comments section.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my question is about the second argument as i wrote in the question.

Comment: @XTard -- The problem with those links (now corrected by actual posting of the code) is that the links may not be permanent, thus making this question useless to persons linking to this thread in the future.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah paul, i understand this and i tried to avoid that, but i had issues, i am pretty new in writing questions in www.stackoverflow.com. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: As to your question, the `std::find` link (which is not the best site for a C++ reference, but that's another thing) says this:  *Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a sequence.* -- So what in that descriptions is not understandable?

Comment: @XTard: Why don't you spend a few days browsing this website and observing how questions progress (noting in particular how successful questions evolve), so you get a feel for how to best approach this site.

Comment: @KerrekSB well i really often use the Stacks for information about many things and fully read both the questions and the answers. But once again, i got issues, i know what do you mean, and i will improve, that's my first question. I believe comments of such kind won't really help answering my question (i am not talking only about your comment, nothing personal), however thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: @XTard  Once you figure out `std::find`, note that this way of filling an array with unique numbers is inefficient.  Imagine if the number of numbers was 1,000 instead of 10 numbers.  Think of using `std::set<int>`,  where you simply just keep looping, inserting random numbers into it, until the set reaches the size you're looking for.  Then that set has unique numbers without basically any effort, and is much more efficient than using `std::find` each time on an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reference:
first, last
Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a sequence. The range searched is [first,last), which contains all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first **but not the element pointed by last.**

I could be mistaken, but I have a hunch it's the last part (in bold) that's confusing you a bit.  The "last" position is EXclusive, so, it will not be searched.

For your 4 element array, therefore:
to search elements 0,1,2,and 3, you want a range of [0,4) (notice the paren instead of the bracket - exclusion vs inclusion, respectively)

**Edited to add**: as for the second part - that's just an initialization issue, I would imagine your int[4], is created with 4 zeroes...

If you want to avoid that, you'll have to keep track of what you've loaded, and only search the valid range.  Of course, your first rand() would need to be put to [0], if you follow

Answer (score 0):

The `std::find` function that you are using has 3 parameters:

1. Pointer (iterator) to beginning of sequence,
2. Pointer (iterator) to end of sequence (last slot + 1)
3. Value to find.

The example you state:
`std::find(randNums, randNums + 4, newRandNum);`

is searching from:
The beginning of the sequence (`randNums`),
The end of the sequence (`randNums + 4`) or 4 positions after the beginning,
for the value `newRandNum`.

Search also for: *pointer arithmetic*, *iterator addition*.

Comment: Doesn't it go up to: `randNums + 3`?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer: The end is always one past the last location.  So the end of the sequence is `randNums + 4`.  The sequence is `randNums[0]` through `randNums[3]` inclusive because `randNums[4]` is past the last slot to be searched.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews got your point too, really liked your explanation it's pretty clear. Thanks for the answer. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the randNum list with -1.

Answer (score 0):

> *The range searched is [first,last), which contains all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the element pointed by last.* - [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

The last is the number of elements that will be searched in the array for the value in a standard `std::find` function like:

```
std::find(randNums, randNums + 4, newRandNum);
```

The range specified here is from the first element in `randNums` to `randNums + 4 - 1`. This means that the value `newRandNum` will be searched between the start of `randNums` and `randNums + 3`, including these 2 values.

Comment: @A Busy Programmer got your point too. Thanks for the answer. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer of the second question. I should set randNums's content to a integer which is different than 0-9.